# zsh: command not found: iodbctest

Tags: database, macos, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, macos-catalina

$ iodbctest
zsh: command not found: iodbctest

I want to configure odbc driver for the snowflake DB on Mac Catalina. I followed the steps in the below link.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-mac.html

ran the following command too
$ brew reinstall freetds

Finally I'm not able to connect to the driver either.

`H (50404) [` getting this error when I try to connect to snowflake.

Comment: Have you installed iodbc for Mac from [here](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/Downloads#Mac%20OS%20X) as it was mentioned on our documentation? If that's done, it may be that **zsh** doesn't know about path for the iodbc executable. To test the ODBC data source connection, you can use the GUI iODBC Administrator64 app or the iODBC command line utilities iodbctest / iodbctestw (Applications > iODBC > iODBCTest.command / iODBCTestUniCode.command). Error 50404 means the connection string is invalid; it should be specified in this format: **dsn=<dsn>;pwd=<password>**

Comment: Can you post a sample code of your Ruby script so I can have a look ?

Comment: I get a 404, is the repo public?

Comment: Oops no. Give me a sec

Comment: I figured it out to be some encoding issue. If I remove `ANSIENCODING=UTF-8` and change `DriverManagerEncoding=UTF-32` to `DriverManagerEncoding=UTF-16` in simba.snowflake.ini`, the connection responds. which is the right one though @Sergiu